# isodate: \date inside \daterange

Tags: date, isodate, locale

I am currently using the `isodate` package to perform locate-specific date formatting.
There are certain dates that I store in variables since I use them throughout the document. Unfortunately, these stored dates cannot be used inside `\daterange`. This can be demonstrated using the following code:

```
\documentclass{scrreport}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[german]{isodate}

\newcommand{\mydate}{\date{2022-10-10}}

\begin{document}
This works: \daterange{2022-10-10}{2022-10-20}\par
%This does not \daterange{\mydate}{2022-10-20}\par
\end{document}
```

Removing the comment leads to the following error message during compilation:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2022-08-30>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrreport.cls
Document Class: scrreport 2022/07/04 v3.37 KOMA-Script document class (report)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrreprt.cls
Document Class: scrreprt 2022/07/04 v3.37 KOMA-Script document class (report)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile-hook.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlogo.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/german.ldf
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/germanb.ldf)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/locale/de/babel-german.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/isodate/isodate.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/substr/substr.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/isodate/german.idf
Define commands for German date format (german)
)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./mwe.aux)
isodate: babel.sty has been loaded
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \equal
                  {\iso@dateformat }{iso}\OR \equal {\iso@dateformat }{TeX}
l.9 This does not \daterange{\mydate}{2022-10-20}
                                                 \par
```

I could redefine `\mydate` as `\newcommand{\mydate}{2022-10-10}` but then I would need to use `\date` everywhere I want to use `\mydate`. Is it possible to place `\date` inside `\daterange`? I am also open to using other packages as long as locale-specific formatting  is possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: no, \date assigns the date you can't use it inside daterange. Do something like `\newcommand{\mydate}{2022-10-10}`, `\newcommand\printmydate{\date{\mydate}}`.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your `\mydate` more simply by `\def\mydate{2022-10-10}` and you can define a "prefix macro" `\paramXX` which expands two parameters before they are read by given macro.

```
\def\paramXX#1#2#3{\expandafter#1\expanded{{#2}{#3}}}
\def\mydate{2022-10-10}
```

Now

```
This works: \paramXX\daterange{\mydate}{2022-10-20}
```